# How to auto refresh / reload once a thank you page when the page is loaded?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, page-refresh

I need to auto refresh a woocommerce thank you page.
I tried the following codes but they didn’t refresh the page.
I added this code in head.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='https://www.mywebsite.com/my-thank-you/'">
```

I added this code in thank you page.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            // Call refresh page function after 5000 milliseconds (or 5 seconds).
            setInterval('refreshPage()', 5000);
        });
    
        function refreshPage() { 
            location.reload(); 
        }
```

It would be a big help if you could teach me how to auto refresh a woocommerce thank you page.

Thank you.

Comment: Add jQuery to refresh dynamically?

Comment: Oh, thank you for your comments, I didn't know jQuery would do. I tried jQuery (I updated the code) but it still doesn't refresh the thank you page though... Could you please help me, if possible?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your meta tag. Are you sure it showed up in the HTML?

Comment: I think it's because the url doesn't match. The url of the thank you page is like this https://www.mywebsite.com/my-thank-you/?key=wc_p80925bbe3453453414&order_id=66. I have no idea how to add dynamic url in meta tag...

Comment: @AloHA_ChiCken: thank you for your help. I got the idea because of your comments and found the jQuery : )

Comment: @Aino Glad that!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone who may need.
I put this jQuery in the thank you page and it refreshes the page.

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```